# How to make selinux give access to apache|nginx in centos 8

Tags: apache-httpd, nginx, selinux

i recently install yii2 app and after all setup i realize that i keep getting permission error and after a lot of search i notice there's nothing wrong with my setup but the problem is with SElinux mode being set to enforcing, so when i try to set the mode to disabled that solve the permission problem so i need help on how to allow SElinux give permission to directory for example

```
/var/www/
```

give permmision to all the content of `/var/www` and the subdirectory

any help would be appreciated

I edited my question to include this portion as I also face the same problem with nginx so i'd appreciate if there's different ways of solving this problem for the two web server because from my search i saw something like

```
chcon -Rv --type=httpd_user_content_rw_t /var/www/html/yii/
```

which specifically mention httpd and to my knowledge i thought it's only referring to apache, so any idea on how to solve same issue for different web server would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

For an individual file in `nginx`, you can change the context like this

```
# semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_content_t /www/file.txt
# restorecon -v /www/file.txt
```

For a group of files, you would do it like this:

```
# semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_content_t /var/www(/.*)?
# restorecon -Rv /var/www/
```

Source: [nginx.com, Option 1: Modify the File Label](https://www.nginx.com/blog/using-nginx-plus-with-selinux/)

Comment: Answer looks good but if I don't use quotation mark around `/var/www(/.*)?` bash complains. Test your solution and change your answer if you got the same conclusion.